# Hide certain posts on tumblr home

Tags: themes, hide, tumblr

I would like to hide certain posts on my tumblr homepage that have the a specific tag (#journal). I've already tried some codes, but it didn't work.

Here is my actual HTML code:

**pastebin.com/JT4KtyVz**

My tumblr:
http://heynotspecial.tumblr.com/

Do you guys know how to do that?

Sorry, not used to post code here :(

Comment: If you say you have already tried some code then you should showcase your effords. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You need to identify a commonality for posts that have the `Journal #` tag. I suspect there could be a class name applied to posts with this tag.

You can apply this rule in your CSS stylesheet to hide `div` elements with the `infscrjournal` classname.

```
{block:HomePage}
div[class~=infscrjournal] {
    display: none;
}
 {/block:HomePage}
```

**** you need to surround the code with the homepage variable to make sure it only appears on the first page and nothing else. Try that

Comment: It works!

But its not showing on the Journal menu I've created on : http://heynotspecial.tumblr.com/search/journal

Just wanted it to not appear on my index